# how can I write an SQL statement to find the average of the rest of a group, for each member of the group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find how far each member of a group differed from the average for the rest of the group.
The distance is easy, but the mean of the rest of the group is eluding me.

For example:

| item | group | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 1 |
| Y | A | 2 |
| Z | A | 3 |

would give:

| Item | groupMean |
| --- | --- |
| X | 2.5 |
| Y | 2 |
| Z | 1.5 |

I am assuming windowed functions would be the way to go, but I seem to have a complete blank as to how to do this in SQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the DBMS you're using?

Comment: Im using SQL server

Comment: Can you show your last coding attempt at this problem? maybe it just needs some quick fix @Paul

Comment: I don't understand the logic: the mean of those three rows is `2` so X should be `-1` etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose an answer based on mathematical equation.

For a group `X,Y and Z`, `AVG = (X+Y+Z) / Count` that applies to
`Y+Z = (AVG * Count) -X`.

`Y+Z` is the sum of the group members without `X`, now we can simply divide `Y+Z` by
`Count -1`to get the average of `Y and Z`.

Check the following query.

```
with stat as
(Select group_, avg(data_) as av,sum(data_) as sm, count(data_) as cn
from MyData
group by group_)

Select MyData.item, MyData.group_,
((stat.av*stat.cn)-MyData.data_) *1.0 / (cn-1) as diff
from stat
inner join MyData
on stat.group_=MyData.group_
```

See the demo from *[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=168a438e1d619ae6100193a9dbf26adc)*.

You may replace `(stat.av*stat.cn)` with `stat.sm`;I used it for the clarification of the equation above.

Comment: If you have a groups with only one row, then you have avoid `division by 0`, you may use `case when stat.cn = 1 then...`

Answer (score 1):

based on the mathematical calculation, I think this will be easy way to calculate:

```
SELECT item, 
((SELECT sum(data) FROM Table where [group] = T.[group]) - data) /
(SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM Table WHERE [group] = T.[group]) < 2 
THEN 1.0  
ELSE  cast(((SELECT count(*) FROM  Table WHERE [group] = T.[group]) - 1) as float) END AS groupMean)
FROM Table as T
```

Calculation is sum of all data minus current data divided by count of all data - 1 (current one), in case of only one item for a group it will return 0

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77283162055e6115925073d8069f0586)
I hope it will help

Comment: This is valid if the table contains only one group. But, as we can see from the table schema, the table contains a `group` field which indicates that it has multiple groups.

Comment: @Ahmed thanks you were right, now it will work for many groups

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using the mathematical approach and here is the SQL query that I ran:

```
SELECT 
    T1.item, 
    T1.[group], 
    T1.[data], 
CASE GroupCount WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE CAST((GroupSum-[data]) AS float)/ CAST((GroupCount -1) AS float) END AS restAverage  FROM MyTable T1
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT count(*) GroupCount, SUM([data]) GroupSum, [group] groupT FROM MyTable GROUP BY [group]) T2
ON T1.[group] = T2.groupT
```

For the Results, I created a dummy table on SQL server and here is what I got at the end:

[image]

Comment: If a group only has one item in it, the result of `(GroupCount -1)` is `0`, and that will cause a divide by zero error.

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you for the comment. I did update my query to handle that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers...  The average *(mean)* of a group is `SUM(data) / COUNT(*)` , and so the average *(mean)* of the rest of the group is `(SUM(data) - this_rows_data) / (COUNT(*) - 1)`

The below query obtains the `SUM(data)` and `COUNT(*)` for the whole group using window functions *(partitioning by the group)*, and then deals with divide by zero errors by using `NULLIF()` to replace zeros with `NULL`.

The leading `1.0 *` is just to coerce the integer values to decimals, as otherwise the results will use integer arithmetic.

```
SELECT
  example.*,
  1.0
  *
        (SUM([data]) OVER (PARTITION BY [group]) - [data])
  /
  NULLIF(COUNT(*)    OVER (PARTITION BY [group]) - 1     , 0)
FROM
  example
ORDER BY
  [group],
  [item]
```

Also, ***please*** don't use reserved keywords like `group` as column names ;)

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7638518964b74924bbd5ac5e42c71b03